# How do I install GHC 7.8.1 and assign it a different command?

Tags: unix, haskell, compiler-construction, build, ghc

I would like to install GHC 7.8.1, but would like to assign it different commands, so as not to clash with 7.6.3. For example:

- `runghc` with `runghc7.8.1`
- `ghci` with `ghci7.8.1`
- etc...

Or similar. (ghci would be most important, for typed holes.)
Basically, I want to be able to use GHC 7.8 and 7.6, so if there is a more direct way to do this tell me (A-B problem.)

Note: Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: On what OS you want to install it?

Comment: I have 7.8.1 and 7.6.3 both installed in separate subdirectories of my home directory. I have a symlink that points to whichever one I want to use at the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are on a unix-like system (Ubuntu) you can do the following:

1. Choose a folder you like for installing ghc (e.g. in a subfolder of your home directory like `$HOME/ghc7.8.1` or in a subfolder of `/opt` like `/opt/ghc7.8.1` – I would prefer the later one if you are the only user of your computer and the first one if this isn't the case). See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_directory_structure#Conventional_directory_layout) for explanations about the unix directory structure.
2. Download the source code into that folder and follow the [installation instructions](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/QuickStart):

   - See also https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/Using#Runtheconfigurescript
   - In configure setp its important, that you set the `--prefix` to the folder you have chosen above (if you don't do this, ghc will be installed in `/usr/local/` which you do not want)! For example:

     ```
      ./configure --prefix=/opt/ghc7.8.1
     ```
3. After the installations look for the folder with the created binaries (it will be called `bin` if you did not use another name for `bindir`). Lets imagine this folder is `/opt/ghc7.8.1/bin`.

Now you have two possibilities:

**Solution with creating [symlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink):** Create symlinks in a folder which is in your `$PATH` pointing to the created binaries (for example `/usr/local/bin` or `$HOME/bin` – I would use the first one, if you are the only user on your computer and the second if, if you are not). Therefore you have to use the command line tool [`ln`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_%28Unix%29). For example:

```
sudo ln -s -T /opt/ghc7.8.1/bin/runghc /usr/local/bin/runghc7.8.1
```

After this command there is a file `/usr/local/bin/runghc7.8.1` pointing to the binary `/opt/ghc7.8.1/bin/runghc`. Executing `/usr/local/bin/runghc7.8.1` via typing `runghc7.8.1` will now execute the `runghc` binary created in `/opt` (Note: `sudo` is not necessary if you create your symlink in `$HOME/bin` – it is just needed because `root` can create files under `/usr`)

**Solution with [bash aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28Unix%29):** Write in your `$HOME/.bash_aliases` (@Others: you can alternatively choose `$HOME/.bashrc` or `$HOME/.profile` depending of your system/preference) the following line:

```
alias runghc7.8.1='/opt/ghc7.8.1/bin/runghc'
```

Now typing `runghc7.8.1` in your terminal is an shortcut (alias) for typing `/opt/ghc7.8.1/bin/runghc` and will execute this binary.

Note, that with this solution typing `runghc7.8.1` will just work, when you typed it into your terminal. There are cases, when it does not work (for example calling `runghc7.8.1` in a script).

Comment: You need to pass `-s` to `ln` in order to create a symlink.

Comment: the aliases look like what I want